# WYSIWYG development bug with formatBlock in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I'am currently developing a WYSIWYG editor for my CMS and got serious bugs here. After switching from IFRAME to DIV contenteditable the behavior changed dramatically.

Using `execCommand('formatBlock')` to create headlines causes unwanted BR tags to the source code, but only in Mozilla. I thought the reason could be `<br _moz_dirty="">` but I could be wrong and did not find a way to fix it.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kj9Rp/

Comment: +1 for complete JSFiddle test case.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a bug. I've noticed that the relatively recently added `contenteditable` functionality in Mozilla has a number of quirks not present with `designMode`. I would stick with the `<iframe>` and `designMode` for now and file a bug at [Mozilla's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Your other option is to write your own DOM manipulation code that surrounds selected text within an `<h1>` element, but that will be relatively involved to get absolutely right.

Comment: I gonna write my own manipulation because old IEs and Safari also seem to be buggy / unsupported.